# How to split line into 0,1, or 2 arrays based on line content

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a program that will receive input lines in one of four structures:

```
a,b
(a,b,c),d
a,(b,c,d)
(a,b),(c,d)
```

the number of members inside each parenthesis might change. Now, I want to translate each of the above lines as following

```
['a','b']
[['a','b','c'],'d']
['a',['b','c','d']]
[['a','b'],['c','d']]
```

I can think of a way to do this by checking each character, but knowing python, I'm certain there is a way to do this easily, probably using regular expressions. Is there?

**Edit:** Edited the desired output.

Comment: What exactly do you want as output: the string `"[a,b]"` or the list `["a","b"]`? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I want to create an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
import re, ast

input = """
a,b
(a,b,c),d
a,(b,c,d)
(a,b),(c,d)
"""

input = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r"'\1'", input)
for line in input.strip().splitlines():
    print ast.literal_eval(line)

> ('a', 'b')
> (('a', 'b', 'c'), 'd')
> ('a', ('b', 'c', 'd'))
> (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
```

This creates tuples, not lists, but that would be an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular expression to replace the parenthesis and then concatenate a [ and ] on the end of the string.

Comment: That gives you the textual representation of a `list`, but it doesn't give you a `list`. OP clarified his request -- he wants an "array of strings."

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression. Use a stack instead:

```
def parse(inputstring):
    result = []
    stack = [result]
    value = ''
    for char in inputstring:
        if char == '(':
            # new context
            if value:
                stack[-1].append(value)
            value = ''
            stack[-1].append([])
            stack.append(stack[-1][-1])
        elif char == ')':
            if value:
                stack[-1].append(value)
            value = ''
            # pop off context
            stack.pop()
        elif char == ',':
            if value:
                stack[-1].append(value)
            value = ''
        else:
            value += char
    if value:
        stack[-1].append(value)
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> parse('a,b')
['a', 'b']
>>> parse('(a,b,c),d')
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ',d']
>>> parse('a,(b,c,d)')
['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]
>>> parse('(a,b),(c,d)')
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
import re

st = """
a,b
(a,b,c),d
a,(b,c,d)
(a,b),(c,d)
"""

def element(e):
    e=e.strip()
    e=re.sub(r'(\w+)',r'"\1"', e)
    e=e.replace('(','[')
    e=e.replace(')',']')
    code=compile('temp={}'.format(e), '<string>', 'exec')
    exec code
    return list(temp)

print [element(x) for x in st.splitlines() if x.strip()]
# [['a', 'b'], [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'], ['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]]
```